# Codeigintieer mostrar array bidireccional

Tags: codeigniter, array-bidimensional

Estoy haciendo una web de test, y tengo hecho un bucle cogiendo preguntas dándome y las voy guardando junto con las opciones. Tengo el campo pregunta (que es la pregunta) y luego un campo opciones que es otro arras con todas las opciones a esa pregunta. Imprimiendo la variable me sale algo tal que así, como debería imprimir por la view?

Array ( [1] => Array ( [Pregunta] => Que poder se encarga de las leyes? [Opciones] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Id_pregunta] => 6 [Id_opcion] => 15 [Opcion] => Legislativo [Respuesta] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [Id_pregunta] => 6 [Id_opcion] => 16 [Opcion] => Judicial [Respuesta] => 0 ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [Pregunta] => Quien gobernó en 2019? [Opciones] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Id_pregunta] => 4 [Id_opcion] => 11 [Opcion] => Psoe [Respuesta] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [Id_pregunta] => 4 [Id_opcion] => 12 [Opcion] => PP [Respuesta] => 0 ) ) ) [3] => Array ( [Pregunta] => ¿Cuando se nombró la Comisión encargada de elaborar el anteproyecto de la Constitución de 1978? [Opciones] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Id_pregunta] => 1 [Id_opcion] => 1 [Opcion] => 26 de julio de 1977 [Respuesta] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [Id_pregunta] => 1 [Id_opcion] => 2 [Opcion] => 25 de julio de 1978 [Respuesta] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [Id_pregunta] => 1 [Id_opcion] => 3 [Opcion] => 31 de octubre de 1978 [Respuesta] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [Id_pregunta] => 1 [Id_opcion] => 4 [Opcion] => 31 de octubre de 1977 [Respuesta] => 0 ) ) ) [4] => Array ( [Pregunta] => Que poder se encarga de las leyes? [Opciones] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Id_pregunta] => 6 [Id_opcion] => 15 [Opcion] => Legislativo [Respuesta] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [Id_pregunta] => 6 [Id_opcion] => 16 [Opcion] => Judicial [Respuesta] => 0 ) ) ) )

Answer (score 0):

lo puedes hacer con un doble ciclo, el primero para recorrer las preguntas y en el segundo las opciones de cada pregunta, algo así:

Imaginemos que el array lo envias a la vista en una variable denominada $cuestionario

```
<?php foreach($cuestionario as $pregunta){ ?>
   <h1><?php echo $pregunta['Pregunta']; ?></h1>
   <?php foreach($pregunta['Opciones'] as $opcion){ ?>
     <input 
       type="radio" 
       name="respuesta[<?php echo $opcion['Id_pregunta'] ?>][]"
       value="<?php echo $opcion['Id_opcion'] ?>"
     >
       <?php echo $opcion['Opcion']; ?>
     </input>
   <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Porsupuesto todo estro dentro de un form para que cuando lo envies recibas en el backend solo las respuestas que han seleccionado para cada pregunta, pues si te fijas el atributo "name" de cada input radio tiene el id de la pregunta asociado.